# Eval in Function Versus Macro in Clojure

Tags: macros, clojure

Consider the following function

```
(defn shove [data fun] (eval `(-> ~data ~fun)))
```

which works as expected here

```
(shove [1 2 3] count)  ;; ~~> 3
```

and even here, where it expectedly fails, because it evaluates `(count)` too early

```
(shove [1 2 3] (count))
;; ~~> clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: clojure.lang.ArityException: 
;;       Wrong number of args (0) passed to: core$count, compiling:(null:5:1)
```

But here, when I define an explicit *form* and pass it to the function as data, all is well:

```
(def move '(count))
(shove [1 2 3] move)  ;; ~~> 3
```

Now, in an attempt to get rid of the explicit call of `eval`, I try

```
(defmacro shovem [data form] `(-> ~data ~form))
```

which works fine

```
(shovem [1 2 3] count)    ;; ~~> 3
(shovem [1 2 3] (count))  ;; ~~> 3
```

but it now unexpectedly fails on the explicitly defined form `move`, with an error that suggests that it evaluates `move` to get `(count)` and then keeps trying to evaluate `(count)`, but in a different way than before.

```
(shovem [1 2 3] move)  
;; ~~> java.lang.ClassCastException: 
;; clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

I'm confused about this error message and I don't know how to get the desired behavior, which is that `shovem` should work on all three kinds of input, bare functions like `count`, parenthesized function forms like `(count)`, and data objects like `move` that evaluate to such forms.

I'm ok with using `eval` in the function version, but, at this point, I realize I don't understand what's going on and I want to complete the exercise so as to improve my understanding.

Comment: try `macroexpand` to see what your macro call is actually generating

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### A solution?

In the most general case, you'd need both a macro and `eval` for this purpose of this exercise, which I assume is for learning (please don't actually *do* this).

For the sake of example, keep `shove` as is, and use as a helper to a modified `shovem`

```
(defn shove [x form] (eval `(-> ~x ~form)))

(defmacro shovem* [x form] 
  (if (seq? form) 
    (if (= 'quote (first form))
      `(-> ~x ~(second form))
      `(-> ~x ~form)) 
    `(shove ~x ~form)))
```

Now, `shovem*` has the semantics you are looking for

```
(def move '(count))

(shovem* [1 2 3] count) ;=> 3
(shovem* [1 2 3] (count)) ;=> 3
(shovem* [1 2 3] '(count)) ;=> 3
(shovem* [1 2 3] move) ;=> 3
(let [f count, d [1 2 3]] (shovem* d f)) ;=> 3
```

---

#### The problem (?) with the original macro

```
user=> (def move '(count))
user=> (defmacro shovem [data form] `(-> ~data ~form))

user=> (macroexpand-1 '(shovem [1 2 3] move))
(clojure.core/-> [1 2 3] move)

user=> (macroexpand-1 '(clojure.core/-> [1 2 3] move)) 
(move [1 2 3])

user=> (macroexpand-1 '(move [1 2 3]))
(move [1 2 3]) ; same, move is not a macro
```

That ends the macro expansion phase. Now `(move [1 2 3])` is code. What happens when it is evaluated?

```
user=> (move [1 2 3])
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

If the why isn't obvious, you need to reconsider the [evaluation rules](http://clojure.org/evaluation). The form `(move [1 2 3])` is a list, and `move` is not special form or a macro. So this is considered a function invocation of `move` on its argument `[1 2 3]`. But what is `move`?

```
user=> (type move)
clojure.lang.PersistentList

user=> (ifn? move)
false
```

So, `move` is not a function and doesn't know how to act like one. It's just a list.

```
user=> (= move (list 'count))
true
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `shovem` gets passed `move` the symbol, not the actual value of move, because it is a macro. So your call to `shovem` gets expanded to:

```
(-> [1 2 3] move)
```

`->` is another macro that implicitly wraps `move` in a list, since it is a symbol, so this code is equivalent to:

```
(-> [1 2 3] (move))
```

That is why, after `->` is fully expanded, it becomes

```
(move [1 2 3])
```

And `move` is a sequence, not a function, hence the `java.lang.ClassCastException`

I'm not sure your goal of making the macro work for all input is feasible, since being a macro that runs prior to any code execution, it doesn't know if the `move` symbol passed is something that should be evaluated (to get (count)) or just used literally. Generally macros know whether, or how many times, each argument should be evaluated, based solely on the form of the arguments passed to it, and not on their run time values.